# Regex to do something only if string has prefix

Tags: swift, regex

I have string "something/w1/w2/". I want to get all string between "/" characters, only if I my string is prefixed by "something".

For example, if string is "something/w1/w2/" I want to get matches "w1", "w2".
And if it is "otherThing/w1/w2/" I don't want to get any matches.

Currently, I am using "(?<=something/).+?(?=/)", but in "something/w1/w2/" it returns only "w1". How can I get also "w2"?

Comment: What is the language or tool? You might use `(?:^something|\G(?!^))/([^/\r\n]+)` if supported. https://regex101.com/r/ynV0T9/1

Comment: The solutions can differ depending on the regex flavor. `(?:\G(?!^)|^something)/\K[^/]+` is a good [PCRE solution](https://regex101.com/r/qA9IIQ/1).

Comment: Thank you for your quick responses!
Language is Swift, and, unfortunately, it returns  "Invalid escape sequence in literal" for both of your suggested solutions.

Comment: Try double escaping the backslash `"(?:^something|\\G(?!^))/([^/\\r\\n]+)"`

Comment: If you have an undeterminable number of slashes, it's probably easier to split on slash and pick out every element exept the first if the string begins with `something/`

Comment: @Thefourthbird
"(?:^something|\\G(?!^))/([^/\\r\\n]+)" works almost as desired, except it returns "something/w1" and "w2" instead of "w1" and "w2".

Comment: @Edgar The matches are in the first capturing group highlighted in green on https://regex101.com/r/ynV0T9/1/

Comment: Is there any particular reason to use a regex?

Comment: If you have ""something/w1/w2/w3" should w3 be included in the result or only w1 and w2, I assume the latter?

Comment: w3 also should be included
I want something like "if string has given prefix, get everything that is between '/' symbols"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use match `something` at the start of the string or get iterative matches using the `\G` anchor matching `/` and a capturing group that matches any char except a `/`

The matches are in the first capturing group.

```
(?:^something|\G(?!^))/([^/\r\n]+)
```

With double escapes:

```
(?:^something|\\G(?!^))/([^/\\r\\n]+)
```

- `(?:` Non capturing group

  - `^something` Match `something` from the start of the string
  - `|` Or
  - `\G(?!^)` Assert position at the end of previous match, not at the start
- `)` Close non capturing group
- `/` match literally
- `([^/\r\n]+)` Capture **group 1** Match 1+ times any char except a `/` or newline

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/ynV0T9/1)

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this without using regex but plain Swift. Check if the string has a prefix and then split by slashes.

```
func extractStringsBetweenSlashes(from string: String, ifPrefix prefix: String) -> [Substring]? {
    guard string.hasPrefix(prefix) else { return nil }
    return string.dropFirst(prefix.count).split(separator: "/")
}

print(extractStringsBetweenSlashes(from: "something/a/b/c/d/e", ifPrefix: "something/")) // Optional(["a", "b", "c", "d", "e"])
print(extractStringsBetweenSlashes(from: "something/abcdef/", ifPrefix: "something/")) // Optional(["abcdef"])
print(extractStringsBetweenSlashes(from: "else/a/b/c/d/e", ifPrefix: "something/")) // nil
```

Comment: Thank you, this is a nice way to resolve this task, but I need to do it using regexes.

Answer (score 1):

You may use

```
let string = "something/w1/w2/"
extension String {
  func findconsecutiveMatches() -> [[String]] {
    let regex = try? NSRegularExpression(pattern: "(?:(?<!\\A)\\G|^something)/([^/]+)", options: [])
    if let matches = regex?.matches(in: self, options:[], range:NSMakeRange(0, self.count)) {
      return matches.map { match in
            return (1..<match.numberOfRanges).map {
                let rangeBounds = match.range(at: $0)
                guard let range = Range(rangeBounds, in: self) else {
                    return ""
                }
                return String(self[range])
            }
      }
   } else {
       return []
   }
 }
}
let result = string.findconsecutiveMatches().flatMap { $0 }
print(result)
// => ["w1", "w2"]
```

The regex is

```
(?:(?<!\A)\G|^something)/([^/]+)
```

**Details**

- `(?:(?<!\A)\G|^something)` - either the end of the previous match or `something` at the start of the string
- `/` - a `/` char
- `([^/]+)` - Group 1: any 1+ more chars other than `/`.